# Checkbox linked with VBA to hide a number of rows

Tags: vba

I am trying to hide and unhide a number of rows when a checkbox is ticked or otherwise. I have created the below code, which is working to hide the rows when the checkbox is unticked, however when I tick it again the rows are not visible. Can anyone assist?

```vb
Private Sub CheckBox3_Click()

'unhide all rows

    Rows("1:138").EntireRow.Hidden = False

    'Hide investment Advice, if checkbox is not marked

    If CheckBox3 = False Then

        Rows("22:29").EntireRow.Hidden = True

    Else

        Rows("22:29").EntireRow.Hidden = False

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: The code works fine for me. How did you create the checkbox? Is there any other code?

Comment: I had a previous code but not linked to the checkbox, to hide the specified rows, however this was deleted. The checkbox was created from the developer and form control

Comment: What is "linked" to the checkbox and why? Your code does not need it... Is there an event dealing with the same range?

Comment: Previously i was trying to use VBA to hide a number of rows based on a cell value, which changes based on an IF function. However it seemed to only work if i manually change the value of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-use-the-forms-controls-on-a-worksheet-in-excel-e7e33c0c-f080-4443-b565-d21b1bdbcf43

1. Set the cell reference for the checkbox as a G2 address or as a range name, for example VISIBLE
2. When a checkbox event occurs, process the value in the cell

```
Sub CheckBox3_Click()
    Rows("22:29").Hidden = Not [Visible] ' VISIBLE i have set as name for G2 range
End Sub
```